# How to get the minimum and maximum of each period in the list?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, graph

This is the graph that I got in the list [image]

**My question is how to get each minimum and maximum of each period in the list?** Following the graph I want to get the 1st maximum at point `1`, 1st minimum at point `30`, 2nd maximum at point `62`, 2nd minimum at point `94`

I have tried but it got the wrong point since the value in the list is not stable as you can see on the graph

This is my code that I have tried

```
max_1 = 0
max_1_pos = 0
min_1_pos = 0
max_2 = 0
max_2_pos = 0
min_2_pos = 0
img_list_pix =[218, 225, 224, 224, 224, 220, 217, 215, 216, 216,
               216, 215, 214, 215, 214, 214, 213, 210, 210, 205,
               207, 204, 205, 201, 200, 201, 201, 197, 202, 203,
               196, 196, 196, 196, 198, 198, 199, 202, 202, 205,
               205, 205, 207, 206, 208, 207, 209, 214, 212, 213,
               215, 218, 220, 219, 218, 220, 223, 222, 224, 224,
               224, 222, 225, 222, 222, 222, 222, 223, 223, 221,
               223, 222, 223, 219, 218, 216, 215, 214, 212, 212,
               211, 211, 207, 206, 205, 204, 202, 199, 199, 198,
               197, 195, 193, 191, 191, 193, 191, 196]

for i in range(len(img_list_pix)):
    if img_list_pix[i] >= max_1:
        max_1 = img_list_pix[i]
        max_1_pos = i
    else:
        break
min_1 = max_1
print(f"max_1:{max_1} | i:{i}")

for i in range(max_1_pos + 1, len(img_list_pix)):
    if img_list_pix[i] <= min_1:
        min_1 = img_list_pix[i]
        min_1_pos = i
    else:
        break
max_2 = min_1
print(f"min_1:{min_1} | i:{i}")

for i in range(min_1_pos + 1, len(img_list_pix)):
    if img_list_pix[i] >= max_2:
        max_2 = img_list_pix[i]
        max_2_pos = i
    else:
        break
min_2 = max_2
print(f"max_2:{max_2} | i:{i}")

for i in range(max_2_pos + 1, len(img_list_pix)):
    if img_list_pix[i] <= min_2:
        min_2 = img_list_pix[i]
        min_2_pos = i
    else:
        break
print(f"min_2:{min_2} | i:{i}")
```

The results of the aforementioned code is:

```
max_1:225 | i:2
min_1:215 | i:8
max_2:216 | i:11
min_2:214 | i:13
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Use of the built-in functions *min* and *max* will help you as will some judicious slicing of your *img_list_pix* list. What output were you hoping to get?

Comment: Your goal is to find local maximas and minimas in an Array ?

Comment: Why does first minimum get triggered at point `30`, in your logic?

Comment: I think 94 must be changed to 93. Is it true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your modified code will be as:

```
F1 = 0
F1_lim = 15
for i in range(len(img_list_pix)):
    if img_list_pix[i] > max_1:
        max_1 = img_list_pix[i]
        max_1_pos = i
        F1 = 0
    elif F1 <= F1_lim:
        F1 += 1
        if img_list_pix[i] > max_1:
            max_1 = img_list_pix[i]
            max_1_pos = i
            F1 = 0
    else:
        F1 = 0
        break
print(f"max_1:{max_1} | i:{max_1_pos}")

min_1 = max_1
for i in range(max_1_pos + 1, len(img_list_pix)):
    if img_list_pix[i] < min_1:
        min_1 = img_list_pix[i]
        min_1_pos = i
        F1 = 0
    elif F1 <= F1_lim:
        F1 += 1
        continue
    else:
        F1 = 0
        break
print(f"min_1:{min_1} | i:{min_1_pos}")

max_2 = min_1
for i in range(min_1_pos + 1, len(img_list_pix)):
    if img_list_pix[i] > max_2:
        max_2 = img_list_pix[i]
        max_2_pos = i
        F1 = 0
    elif F1 <= F1_lim:
        F1 += 1
        if img_list_pix[i] > max_2:
            max_2 = img_list_pix[i]
            max_2_pos = i
            F1 = 0
    else:
        F1 = 0
        break
print(f"max_2:{max_2} | i:{max_2_pos}")

min_2 = max_2
for i in range(max_2_pos + 1, len(img_list_pix)):
    if img_list_pix[i] < min_2:
        min_2 = img_list_pix[i]
        min_2_pos = i
        F1 = 0
    elif F1 <= F1_lim:
        F1 += 1
        continue
    else:
        F1 = 0
        break
print(f"min_2:{min_2} | i:{min_2_pos}")
```

`F1_lim` is number of indices after index of the founded value to compare with, and can be changed by the user. This code will gives the following results:

```
max_1:225 | i:1
min_1:196 | i:30
max_2:225 | i:62
min_2:191 | i:93
```

The code will gives the first occurrence of the minimum or maximum values for valleys or peaks, e.g. for `min_2` it will return **93**. For getting the last one with the same magnitude as *93* i.e. **96** for `min_2` in the specified range `F1_lim = 15`, *less than* and *greater than* operators must be substituted by *less than equal* and *greater than equal* operators.

Answer (score 0):

You should first filter your list by using something like :

```
def low_pass_filter(L, alpha = 0.2):
    filtered_L = []
    for i in range(1,len(L)-1):
        filtered_L.append(L[i-1] * alpha + L[i] * (1-2*alpha) + L[i+1]*alpha)
    return filtered_L
```

Then you can find the extremums of your list by using :

```
def extremums(L):
    """
    This function will only find the local extremums where the derivative should be zero
    """
    maximums = {} #index -> value
    minimums = {} #index -> value
    for i in range(1,len(L)-1):
        if  L[i-1] <= L[i] > L[i+1] or L[i-1] < L[i] >= L[i+1]:
            maximums[i] = L[i] #add this value to maximums
        elif L[i-1] >= L[i] < L[i+1] or L[i-1] > L[i] <= L[i+1]:
            minimums[i] = L[i] #add this value to manimums
    return maximums, minimums
    

L = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 0, 5, 8, 7]

print("Maximums :",extremums(L)[0])
print("Minimums :",extremums(L)[1])
```

outputs :

```
Maximums : {2: 3, 4: 2, 7: 8}
Minimums : {3: 1, 5: 0}
```

- If an extremum was in the beginning or the end of the list, it won't be outputed
- The output is a dictionnary that contains "index->value"

Answer (score 0):

Does this help:

```
img_list_pix = [218, 225, 224, 224, 224, 220, 217, 215, 216, 216,
                216, 215, 214, 215, 214, 214, 213, 210, 210, 205,
                207, 204, 205, 201, 200, 201, 201, 197, 202, 203,
                196, 196, 196, 196, 198, 198, 199, 202, 202, 205,
                205, 205, 207, 206, 208, 207, 209, 214, 212, 213,
                215, 218, 220, 219, 218, 220, 223, 222, 224, 224,
                224, 222, 225, 222, 222, 222, 222, 223, 223, 221,
                223, 222, 223, 219, 218, 216, 215, 214, 212, 212,
                211, 211, 207, 206, 205, 204, 202, 199, 199, 198,
                197, 195, 193, 191, 191, 193, 191, 196]


def getminmax(L, i):
    _min = min(L[i:])
    _max = max(L[i:])
    return (_min, L[i:].index(_min)+i), (_max, L[i:].index(_max)+i)


for i in [0, 29, 61, 93]:
    print(getminmax(img_list_pix, i))
```